# Shortcuts problem, CTRL ALT

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I tried to turn on backlight on keyboard and entered command `sudo xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'`, now my shortcuts are not working.

Can someone please help me? :D

Comment: Title says ctrl alt, question says scroll lock.

Comment: Where did you find that command? How is that expected to turn on your keyboard backlight? Did you log out then back in? The issue should be gone then, because the command you issued is only valid during the current session. Be carefull, and do not shoot around with sudo command you do not understand: next time, you will severely break your system.